# Laravel: Some routes doesn't work if it come after another route in the `routes.php` file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm building a project with Laravel 5.2, and in `routes.php` file I have the next 2 routes:

```
Route::get("/products/{id}", [
    "as"   => "products.show",
    "uses" => "ProductsController@show",
]);

Route::get("/products/search", [
    "as"   => "products.search",
    "uses" => "ProductsController@search",
]);
```

In this order, the first route `products.show` works fine and as expected, but the second route `products.search` does not, it gives a blank webpage instead of the expected search results.

I've tried to fix the problem by changing their orders and placing the `products.search` route before the `products.show` route, and when I did that it worked fine and as expected.

So, what is wrong? And why this happens?

P.S: Another solution was to place the next rule in the beginning of the `route.php` file:

```
Route::pattern("id", "[0-9]+");
```

And when I added this rule, both routes worked find, and it doesn't matter which one comes first. But what if I didn't add this rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routing system stops as soon as it finds a match. So let's say you have these three:

```
Route::get("/products/{variableA}" // ...
Route::get("/products/{variableB}" // ...
Route::get("/products/{variableC}" // ...
```

Now you go to `/products/someroute`. Only the first one will trigger, and the two following ones will never activate.

Your pattern constraint means that when you go to `/products/search`, the first one won't trigger, because it's looking for a numeric `{id}` variable.

Without that constraint, `{id}` could be anything - like the string `search` for instance. So then, then second route doesn't trigger. So you'd need to put them in reverse order for it to work.

You can also use route model binding, which you can read about here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding